# Event Reminders Popup window for Partner Users

Tags: configuration, popup-window, activity-settings

I am able to receive activity(task/event) reminder popup window for Internal users.

But the same window is not available for Partner/Community users, Am I missing any configuration setting?

**Task Reminders for Partner Users**
As per [Summer 14](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_networks_additional_enhancements.htm) Release Notes,

Task reminders are now available to partner users in communities. This includes users with a partner portal or Partner Community license.
Partner users in communities can see their reminders by clicking **Your Name | My Settings | Reminders**.

I am unable to find this setting for partner/community users.